# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' file not found

Tags: android

After update import my old project in android studio we get this errors when build project

```
C:\Users\admin\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-sw360dp-notlong-xhdpi-v13\values-sw360dp-notlong-xhdpi-v13.xml  
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**
```

Search lot on SO but not resolve the error.

Comment: share your **`Build.Gradle`**

Answer (score 1):

AAPT2 still has some issues with long paths on windows (longer than around 145 characters). It is being worked on and the fix should be released in the next major release. In the meantime you can disable AAPT2 or try to make the file path shorter (move the project closer to C:/ and/or change the file name or the values directory name to be shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade the gradle version to which you are using in your old project.
or you can try setting `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`
in your project level build.gradle file

Comment: can  you clarify why we getting error with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

Comment: because your old project is created with lower version of gradle and the newer version has so many changes..either you downgrade the gradle or make changes in your old project according to latest gradle

Answer (score 0):

**Delete .gradle folder**

[image]

**then Invalidate Catches/Restart..**

[image]